# Tastypie - Jquery mobile - Phonegap app Sequence

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, tastypie

I plan on making an iPhone app for my web application using jQuery mobile.

I've already made my Tastypie API. I am just not sure where to take it from here.

Should I first finish my jQuery mobile app and then look into Phonegap? or is there a different way to go about making a Phonegap app? I am the only developer, so I want to be as efficient as I can.

I am thinking of making a web app using Tastypie and jQuery mobile and then Connect that to Phonegap at the end. is this the right way to go about it? Any advice in this aspect with me very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , I am using Tastypie For my mobile devlopement .but i am using titanium .... anyways  tasty pie is a good resource ..

tastypie is an api service if you getting data using tastypie in your jquery app . first check all data resources are working propery .atlast you can compile it with phonegap to get final output. once it compiled we cant change any code since it is like binary or .app code ..

so make sure all your data fetching is working good then proceed to phonegap..

main advantage of tastypie we can easily access the data models of django and perform operations like insertion,fetching etc....

**Things to be followed**

1. make all your data ready using tasty pie . i mean your backend
   models.
2. use them in your jquery app . .
3. test thoroughly
   and at last you can submit to phonegap..